# Integrating $\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{4\pi} \left| \cos \theta \right| \,d\theta $

Tags: calculus, integration

How is this integral
$$\dfrac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{4\pi} \left| \cos \theta \right| \; d\theta$$
 equal to 
$$\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left| \cos \theta \right| \; d\theta$$

On attempting to solve this integral, found this on a solution manual, I know how to integrate it, but I don't know how are these two equal to one another?

Comment: $|\cos x|$ is $\pi$-periodic, hence both integrals equal $\pi$ times the mean value of $|\cos x|$, i.e.$2$.

Comment: You can simplify it further to $\int_0^\pi|\cos\theta|d\theta$, or even $2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta d\theta$.

Comment: The first integral is just the second one done twice. From 2π to 4π it is _exactly_ the same function as from 0 to 2π. You can go even further: it is periodic with period π, so the integral from 0 to 2π is just two lots of the integral from o to π, and the integral from 0 to 4π is just four lots of it. ¶ Actually you can reduce it _yet further_, as the function from zero to π is two mirror-image half-lobes next to each other ... and if you are integrating over the whole half-lobe, the integral of the mirror-image is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the integral: $$\int_{0}^{4 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta + \int_{2 \pi}^{4 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta,$$ then consider the change of variable $\alpha = \theta - 2 \pi$, so the RHS above becomes \begin{align} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta + \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\alpha +2\pi)| d\alpha \\ = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta + \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\alpha)| d\alpha,\end{align} since the cosine function is $2 \pi$ periodic. Who cares whether we use $\alpha$ or $\theta$ as the variable of integration in the second term, i.e., $$ \int_{0}^{4 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta + \int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta.$$ The rest easily follows, regarding your question.

In a similar fashion, as in the suggestion made by Snookie, you can deduce $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta = 2\int_{0}^{ \pi} |\cos(\theta)| d\theta$, and furthermore $\int_0^{\pi} |\cos(\theta)| d \theta = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos(\theta) d \theta + \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin(\theta) d \theta = 2$.

Therefore, $\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{4\pi} |\cos(\theta)| d \theta = \frac{1}{4}\times 4 \times 2 = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula $$\int_{0}^{2a}f(x)\,dx=2\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\,dx$$ provided $f$ satisfies $f(2a-x)=f(x)$. The formula above is proved by splitting the integral as sum of integrals over $[0,a]$ and $[a, 2a]$ and then using substitution $x=2a-t$ in second integral.

Using this formula repeatedly we have $$\int_{0}^{4\pi}|\cos x|\, dx=2\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos x|\, dx=4\int_{0}^{\pi}|\cos x|\, dx=8\int_{0}^{\pi/2}|\cos x|\, dx=8$$

Answer (score 0):

Remember the integral represents a limit of a sum of areas. $d\theta$ represents a change in $\theta$, the width of a rectangle. The value of the function represents the height. If the change in $\theta$ is constant, then all the rectangles have the same width. If you reach an interval where the heights of rectangles, i.e. the function values, or the same as they were on some previous interval, you are adding congruent rectangles. Adding contributions to the area from this section of the interval is the same as doubling the area already covered integrating through the early region. The cosine is a periodic function of period $2\pi$. So it achieves the same function values going from 0 to $2\pi$ as it does from $2\pi$ to $4\pi$.

Do you see any examples in those integral expressions in which part of an interval is ignored while what remains is doubled?